# UserDefaults Does not show up data?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am Presenting a View with some text field and button where user can enter some data in that text field and when the user will click the save button that data will be saved in NSUserdefaults and show it on another view but its not working.. Any suggestion plz..

> View2 code Which is presented over view1

```
//The default key value
var _billingAddress = "billingAddress"

//The address text field in present view
@IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!


//The button action code
 @IBAction func saveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setValue(address.text, forKey:_billingAddress)

 }
```

> View1 code to access the key value data

```
//Label where i want to show the saved value
@IBOutlet weak var billingAddresh: UILabel!

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let name = defaults.stringForKey(_billingAddress)
        //Here it shows the error use of unresolved identifier _billingAddress
    {
        billingAddresh.text = name
    }
```

Its not showing any value 
Thank you for the help..

Comment: Do not use `synchronize()` when reading from user defaults.

Comment: brother your code is correct m but only one mistake you missed the key name of  `_billingAddress` , in here add something like `var _billingAddress = "kk002able"

Comment: Sir when I ctrl click the ...rKey(_billingAddress) it navigate me to the correct variable ie var _billingAddress = "billingAddress" But Still the same error sir , unresolved identifier. any suggestion !!

Comment: `var _billingAddress` is declared in one view controller and is not visible in the other. Use a literal string for the key `billingAddress` like in Anbu.Karthik's answer.

Comment: @kk002able -- can you send your project to my mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com , I will check the issue

Comment: @vadian -- I forget that , bro actually you declared the variable in another class  but you are acccessing the key in another class that the reason you get the erroe `unresolved identifier.`, try once in my updated answer, it will resolve your issue

Comment: Now its working Sir ..Thanks a lot..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add on that time we need the `defaults.synchronize()`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setValue(address.text, forKey:"billingAddress")

// if you want use else ignore 
defaults.synchronize()
```

retrieve is

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let name = defaults.stringForKey("billingAddress") // not "_billingAddress"
{
    billingAddresh.text = name
}

// no need in here 
defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: `we need the defaults.synchronize()` **No we don't.** All defaults.synchronize() does is to make the code *pause* for a few milliseconds, to let time for the defaults to synchronize *if the app or the system is under pressure*. In normal conditions, not only defaults.synchronize() is useless but it can slow down the processes execution. Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/

Comment: @EricD. -- tanx buddy , I thought if we save the synchronize is manodary , tanx a lot

Comment: I know this is a common belief. That's why I made this comment. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sir,

Comment: but while using in view1 if let name = defaults.stringForKey(_billingAddress) this shows unresolve identifer _billingAddress error